# PyQt QTreeWidget problem with custom delegate

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget, qitemdelegate

I'm trying to write simple property editor. I have automatically generated pyqt class (WorkZone in the code below), and I need to view/edit some of it's properties with PropertyEditor, with the delegate PropertyEditorDelegate, that uses custom editors ColorEditor, LineEditor, etc.

Main idea is that WorkZone knows what properties need to be edited and how, and PropertyEditor parse WorkZone, seek for such a properties, and fill QTreeWidget with their values.

But there is a problem: delegate does not start editing on double click, or 'Enter', or smth. It is added to right row, it paints the item, but that's all.
Additionally, when I switched Propertyeditor container's type to QTableWidget, delegate started to work more proper (but editor painted in the corner of the screen, not in the table)!

PS. And one additional question: is there any way to add some delegates to rows without a need to store the instances of them somewhere else (self._delegates in a script), it is just UGLY. Method setItemDelegate accepts pointer to delegate, and in C++ it gets ownership on it, but in PyQT it is not so... Beside, there is no such problem with setItem, for example.

Following script illustrates the problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import inspect


class LineEditor(QtGui.QLineEdit):


    def __init__(self, name = None, parent = None, slot = None):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        self.textChanged.connect(slot)
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def paintForDelegate(delegate, painter, option, index):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(delegate, painter, option, index)

    def get(self):
        return str(self.text())

    def set(self, val):
        self.setText(QtCore.QString.fromUtf8(val))

class ColorEditor(QtGui.QComboBox):


    def _populateList(self):
        for name in QtGui.QColor.colorNames():
            self.addItem(name)
            index = self.findText(name)
            self.setItemData(index, QtGui.QColor(name), QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)

    def __init__(self, name = None, parent = None, slot = None):
        QtGui.QComboBox.__init__(self, parent)
        self._populateList()
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(slot)
        self.name = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8(name)

    @staticmethod
    def paintForDelegate(delegate, painter, option, index):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(delegate, painter, option, index)

    def get(self):
        qColor = QtGui.QColor(self.itemData(self.currentIndex(), QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole))        
        color = ((qColor.blue() | (qColor.green() << 8)) | (qColor.red() << 16))
        return color

    def set(self, val):
        blue = (val & 255)
        green = ((val & 65280) >> 8)
        red = ((val & 16711680) >> 16)
        color = QtGui.QColor(red, green, blue)
        index = self.findData(color, QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        self.setCurrentIndex(index) 

class PropertyEditorDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):


    def __init__(self, object, propName, parent = None):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self._object = object
        self._propName = propName

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self._object.paintForDelegate(self._propName, self, painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return self._object.createEditor(self._propName)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        editor.set(value)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if index.column() == 0:
            model.setData(index, editor.name, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            model.setData(index, editor.get(), QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

class PropertyEditor(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self._object = None
        self._delegates = []
        self._mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self._mainLayout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        self._mainLayout.setSpacing(2)
        self.setLayout(self._mainLayout)
        self._contents = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self._contents.setColumnCount(2)
        self._contents.currentItemChanged.connect(self.printCurrent)
        self._mainLayout.addWidget(self._contents)

    def printCurrent(self, curr, prev):
        print self._contents.currentIndex().row()
        print self._contents.currentIndex().column()
        print self._contents.itemDelegate(self._contents.currentIndex())._propName
        print self._contents.itemDelegate(self._contents.currentIndex())

    def object(self):
        return self._object

    def setObject(self, value):       
        self._object = value

        def isProperty(p):
            return isinstance(p, property)

        for (name, value) in inspect.getmembers(type(self._object), isProperty):
            if self._object.isEditable(name):
                item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
                item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, QtCore.QString.fromUtf8(self._object.getPropertyName(name)))
                item.setData(1, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, self._object.get(name))
                self._contents.addTopLevelItem(item)

                self._delegates.append(PropertyEditorDelegate(self._object, name, self._contents))
                index = self._contents.indexOfTopLevelItem(item)    
                self._contents.setItemDelegateForRow(index, self._delegates[index])

class WorkZone(object):


    def __init__(self):

        self._name = ''
        self.currentEditor = None
        self.red = 100
        self.green = 100
        self.blue = 100
        self._width = 1

    def _getColor(self):
        color = ((self.blue | (self.green << 8)) | (self.red << 16))
        return color

    def _setColor(self, color):
        self.blue = (color & 255)
        self.green = ((color & 65280) >> 8)
        self.red = ((color & 16711680) >> 16)

    color = property(_getColor, _setColor)

    def currentColorChanged(self, index):
        if self.currentEditor is not None:
            self.color = self.currentEditor.get()
        print self.color

    def currentNameChanged(self, newName):
        if self.currentEditor is not None:
            self.name = self.currentEditor.get()
        print self.name

    def createEditor(self, prop):
        if prop == 'color':
            self.currentEditor = ColorEditor('Color', None, self.currentColorChanged)
            self.currentEditor.set(self.color) 
            return self.currentEditor
        elif prop == 'name':
            self.currentEditor = LineEditor('Name', None, self.currentNameChanged) 
            self.currentEditor.set(self.name)
            return self.currentEditor
        else:
            return None

    def releaseEditor(self):
        self.currentEditor = None

    def isEditable(self, prop):
        if prop == 'color':
            return True
        elif prop == 'name':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def set(self, prop, val):
        if prop == 'color':
            self.color = val
        elif prop == 'name':
            self.name = val

    def get(self, prop):
        if prop == 'color':
            return self.color
        elif prop == 'name':
            return self.name

    def getPropertyName(self, prop):
        if prop == 'color':
            return 'Color'
        elif prop == 'name':
            return 'Name'

    def paintForDelegate(self, prop, delegate, painter, option, index):
        if prop == 'color':
            ColorEditor.paintForDelegate(delegate, painter, option, index)
        elif prop == 'name':
            LineEditor.paintForDelegate(delegate, painter, option, index)

    def _setWidth(self, Width):
        self._width = Width

    def _getWidth(self):
        return self._width

    width = property(_getWidth, _setWidth)

    def _getName(self):
        return self._name

    def _setName(self, val):
        self._name = val

    name = property(_getName, _setName)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    zone = WorkZone()
    zone.color = 0
    zone.width = 1
    propertyEditor = PropertyEditor()
    propertyEditor.setObject(zone)


    propertyEditor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up handling the double click to set to editable, force the item in to edit mode with editItem() and then set it back. The delegate itself handles all the display and editing.

```
# In __init__:
    self.tree.itemActivated.connect(self.onDoubleClick)


def onDoubleClick(self, item, index):
    """ 
    The logic will happen in the editor delegate. This is needed to let
    the delegate run by making this editable
    """        
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)            

    # Force the item in to edit mode so the delegate picks it up
    self.tree.editItem(item, index)

    # Set the item back to not editable. The delegate will still do its
    #    job, but the read-only state will already be set when done!
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
```

The first setFlags probably only needs ItemIsEditable to work, but this felt right.

Answer (score 1):

On PS.

From documentation of PyQt

QAbstractItemView.setItemDelegate (self, QAbstractItemDelegate)

Sets the item delegate for this view and its model to delegate. This is useful if you want complete control over the editing and display of items.

Any existing delegate will be removed, but not deleted. *QAbstractItemView* **does not take ownership of delegate**.

Warning: You should not share the same instance of a delegate between views. Doing so can cause incorrect or unintuitive editing behavior since each view connected to a given delegate may receive the closeEditor() signal, and attempt to access, modify or close an editor that has already been closed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, as always.. %)
Default flags for QTreeWidgetItem do not include QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable.